# Fastest insertion method wanted

Tags: ado.net, informix

The question is simple enough. I have a DataTable object filled with about 200.000 records which needs to be sent into a temporary table in the database. How to do it in a most performant way possible?

IfxBulkCopy is not an option unfortunately since the algorithm involved will be a part of a larger transaction.

I did some tests before and found that calling stored procedure which has INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... is marginally better than calling directly INSERT command but both were considerably slower alternatives.

In my early days of working in Profilics tools on AIX we had insert cursors available which were pretty fast. Perhaps I'm not aware of another option using .NET Informix client (DRDA)?

Comment: Why doesn't a Bulk Copy work again? At the very least it should be possible to use a staging table.

Comment: It doesn't work under a transaction. Altough, I've found an IBM ticket http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1JR31903 which suggests that my conclusion is premature?

Comment: Nope, IfxBulkCopy doesn't work under transaction.

Comment: @Nezreli , did you effectively test the `ifxBulkCopy` or suppose it will not work because of the article you found? The article mentioned is a defect report for old version of the engine which probably should be OK for the last versions...

Comment: Yes, I did. With the latest version IBM.Data.Informix ver. 9.7.4.4 the exception generated leaves no doubt: IfxBulkCopy can not operate under transactional control. I've even tried using the DB2 DRDA drivers which ultimately gave me the same exception. However, I'm pleasantly surprised that they connected and worked without a glitch.